# Find Better Way to Create Paths in JavaScript for Maximum Captures

Tags: javascript, graph-algorithm, breadth-first-search

I have been working on algorithm for a week at last I have successfully made an algorithm to create paths that captures opponent pieces, and then find a Maximum captures Path on 8x8 board.

I have created an array of the following move captures. 
[image: Captures]

```
var moves = [[37 , 69] , [69 , 101] , [ 101 , 99] , [69 ,71], [ 69 , 67] , [67 , 99] , [99 , 101] ,  [71 ,103] ]
```

**Note:** Can't capture downwards respective to black.

Here I don't know the end point so that's why I can use Search Algorithms such as BFS, DFS, e.t.c.

So I decided to first find all the possible captures which are added in moves array hard coded for now.

Then created algorithm which create paths but the complexity of algorithm is much higher but I need the same work with better algorithm.

**Here is my Algorithm**

```
var getPaths = GetPaths(moves);
function GetPaths(moves) {
    var paths = [];
    for (var x = 0 ; x < moves.length ; x++) {
        var path = [];
        for (var y = x + 1 ; y < moves.length ; y++) {
            if (moves[x][1] == moves[y][0]) {
                if (!(path.includes(moves[x]))) {
                    path.push(moves[x]);
                }
                var data = [moves[y][0], moves[y][1]];
                path.push(data);
            }
        }
        if (path.length > 0) paths.push(path);



    }

    var newpaths = [];

    var nextRow = paths[0];
    var len = paths.length;


    for (var h = 1 ; h < nextRow.length; h++) {

        for (var j = 1 ; j < len ; j++) {
            var newpath = [];
            if (isInArray(nextRow[h], paths[j][0])) {

                newpath.push(nextRow[0]);
                var nextfound = false;
                for (var k = j + 1 ; k < paths.length ; k++) {
                    if (isInArray(paths[j][paths[j].length - 1], paths[k][0])) {
                        newpath.push(paths[j][0]);
                        if (paths[k][0][0] - paths[k][0][1] != -(paths[k][1][0] - paths[k][1][1])) {
                            newpath.push(paths[k]);
                        } else {
                            newpath.push(paths[k][0]);
                        }

                        nextfound = true;
                    }

                }
                if (!nextfound) {
                    newpath.push(paths[j]);
                }

            }
            if (newpath.length > 0) {
                newpaths.push(newpath);
            }
        }

    }

    return newpaths;
}

var maxPath = FindMaximumCapture(getPaths);
function FindMaximumCapture(totalPaths) {
    var max = totalPaths[0].toString().length;

    var index = 0;
    for (var count = 1 ; count < totalPaths.length ; count++) {
        if (max < totalPaths[count].toString().length) {
            max = totalPaths[count].toString().length;
            index = count;
        }
    }
    return totalPaths[index];
}
function isInArray(value, array) {
    return array.indexOf(value[0]) > -1 && array.indexOf(value[1]) > -1;
}
```

Here is the link of code in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/64Ltjz0k/)

Comment: What do those tuples in the `moves` array mean, how do they correlate to the chess problem?

Comment: they are the locations of jumps for black pieces e.g moves[0] is 37 , 69 which means black can move from 37 (existing position of black) to 69  to capture white piece at 53.

Comment: But what is "position 37"? Or especially "position 69", on a board with only 64 fields?

Comment: yeah there are 64 fields but this code contains array of size 128 0-7 for first line and 8-15 is for reflection of the board so next line starts with 16 and ends on 23 and so on.

Comment: and 37 is board array index where black piece is located.